# sanitizing/escaping plugin options

Tags: plugin-development, jquery

I have a plugin with a few text boxes that save the data in a serialized manner, the array is localized and printed in website front end to display custom messages. However, I just noticed that you can add html and javascript inside the text boxes, is there anyway to disallow this kind of content?

Answer (score 1):

```
sanitize_text_field( $str )
```

- Sanitize a string from user input or from the db.
- Checks for invalid UTF-8, Convert single < characters to entity,
  strip all tags, remove line breaks, tabs and extra white space, strip
  octets

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field

Comment: Can I do something in the type text like `value="<?php $title = sanitize_text_field(get_option('lu_ban_data')); echo $title['title']; ?>"`

Comment: You would use sanitize_text_field() before saving the value with update_option(). When retrieving the option, I believe you will need to convert html entities back to characters: $title = htmlspecialchars_decode(get_option('lu_ban_data')); echo $title;